# AMD Radeon Instinct MI25 fails to initialize: [drm:amdgpu_device_fw_loading [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hw_init of IP block <psp> failed -22

Tags: linux, amd-graphics-card

I picked up a cheap used MI25 card and put it into my computer running Debian in the hopes of doing some ROCm-accelerated number crunching (like machine learning). The kernel failed to initialize the card, leading to udev crashing and the boot taking a very long time. The following can be seen on the screen:

```
[    6.464978] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: amdgpu: MEM ECC is active.
[    6.465759] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: amdgpu: SRAM ECC is not presented.
[    6.466466] [drm] vm size is 262144 GB, 4 levels, block size is 9-bit, fragment size is 9-bit
[    6.467209] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 16368M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F7FEFFFFFF (16368M used)
[    6.468262] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF
[    6.469079] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: amdgpu: AGP: 267419648M 0x000000F800000000 - 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF
[    6.469908] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=16368M, BAR=16384M
[    6.470728] [drm] RAM width 2048bits HBM
[    6.471573] [drm] amdgpu: 16368M of VRAM memory ready
[    6.472547] [drm] amdgpu: 64236M of GTT memory ready.
[    6.473345] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 131072, num gpu pages 131072
[    6.474611] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled.
[    6.475489] [drm] PTB located at 0x000000F400900000
[    6.476485] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_sos.bin
[    6.477645] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_asd.bin
[    6.478433] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: amdgpu: PSP runtime database doesn't exist
[    6.479257] amdgpu: [powerplay] hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is vega10_smu
[    6.480187] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_smc.bin
[    6.480973] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_pfp.bin
[    6.481765] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_me.bin
[    6.482596] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_ce.bin
[    6.483340] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_rlc.bin
[    6.484159] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_mec.bin
[    6.485022] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_mec2.bin
[    6.486890] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_uvd.bin
[    6.487735] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 66.43 Family ID: 17
[    6.488446] [drm] PSP loading UVD firmware
[    6.490195] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vega10_vce.bin
[    6.491051] [drm] Found VCE firmware Version: 57.6 Binary ID: 4
[    6.491994] [drm] PSP loading VCE firmware
[    6.770117] [drm:psp_hw_start [amdgpu]] *ERROR* PSP load sos failed!
[    6.770973] [drm:psp_hw_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* PSP firmware loading failed
[    6.771657] [drm:amdgpu_device_fw_loading [amdgpu]] *ERROR* hw_init of IP block <psp> failed -22
[    6.772277] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_init failed
[    6.772890] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
[    6.773568] amdgpu 0000:10:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.
[    6.789336] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000090
```

How do I get this card working? I tried many things including various permutations of all BIOS settings that seemed even remotely relevant (above 4G decoding, CSM/UEFI, etc). I also tried both newer and older kernels, as well as using the custom kernel tree from AMD, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

(I found my own solution, sorry if this is bad etiquette. I just don't want anyone else to suffer through this, and I hate the idea of people throwing away perfectly good silicon.)

First of all, before doing anything, take note of the fact that the card is passively cooled. That means you **must** install your own fan and "shroud" (wind funnel). Do not power on the card without adequate cooling! The magic smoke might come out!

### Solution

After a lot of debugging and desperate attempts, I figured out that the reason behind the crash is that the firmware takes too long to initialize on the card for whatever reason, so the driver times out and crashes. My solution is just to patch the Linux kernel to increase the timeout from 20 ms to 500 ms:

```
--- drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/psp_v3_1.c       2022-10-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0100
+++ drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/psp_v3_1.c       2022-10-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0100
@@ -107,21 +107,21 @@
        psp_copy_fw(psp, psp->sys.start_addr, psp->sys.size_bytes);
 
        /* Provide the sys driver to bootloader */
        WREG32_SOC15(MP0, 0, mmMP0_SMN_C2PMSG_36,
               (uint32_t)(psp->fw_pri_mc_addr >> 20));
        psp_gfxdrv_command_reg = PSP_BL__LOAD_SYSDRV;
        WREG32_SOC15(MP0, 0, mmMP0_SMN_C2PMSG_35,
               psp_gfxdrv_command_reg);
 
        /* there might be handshake issue with hardware which needs delay */
-       mdelay(20);
+       mdelay(500);
 
        ret = psp_wait_for(psp, SOC15_REG_OFFSET(MP0, 0, mmMP0_SMN_C2PMSG_35),
                           0x80000000, 0x80000000, false);
 
        return ret;
 }
 
 static int psp_v3_1_bootloader_load_sos(struct psp_context *psp)
 {
        int ret;
@@ -146,21 +146,21 @@
        psp_copy_fw(psp, psp->sos.start_addr, psp->sos.size_bytes);
 
        /* Provide the PSP secure OS to bootloader */
        WREG32_SOC15(MP0, 0, mmMP0_SMN_C2PMSG_36,
               (uint32_t)(psp->fw_pri_mc_addr >> 20));
        psp_gfxdrv_command_reg = PSP_BL__LOAD_SOSDRV;
        WREG32_SOC15(MP0, 0, mmMP0_SMN_C2PMSG_35,
               psp_gfxdrv_command_reg);
 
        /* there might be handshake issue with hardware which needs delay */
-       mdelay(20);
+       mdelay(500);
        ret = psp_wait_for(psp, SOC15_REG_OFFSET(MP0, 0, mmMP0_SMN_C2PMSG_81),
                           RREG32_SOC15(MP0, 0, mmMP0_SMN_C2PMSG_81),
                           0, true);
        return ret;
 }
 
 static int psp_v3_1_ring_init(struct psp_context *psp,
                              enum psp_ring_type ring_type)
 {
        int ret = 0;
```

This allows the card to boot successfully. There are two more caveats to consider when using this card:

1. Do **not** use the system-provided OpenCL implementation. In my case, it crashes the card and forces a GPU reset. To be safe, I disabled `mesa.icd` by renaming it in `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/`.
2. For whatever reason, my GPU has a BIOS power limit of 110W instead of the rated 300W. There is [a workaround](https://superuser.com/questions/1747746/amd-gpu-radeon-instinct-mi25-accelerator-has-a-power-limit-of-110w-but-it-shou), also involving a kernel patch.