# AMD GPU (Radeon Instinct MI25 accelerator) has a power limit of 110W but it should be able to do 300W

Tags: linux, amd-graphics-card

I cannot seem to increase the power limit on my AMD GPU beyond 110W, I can't even get close to the TDP rating of 300W:

```
ghoti@fish:~$ cat /sys/class/drm/card1/device/hwmon/hwmon2/power1_cap
110000000
ghoti@fish:~$ echo 120000000 | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card1/device/hwmon/hwmon2/power1_cap
[sudo] password for ghoti: 
120000000
tee: /sys/class/drm/card1/device/hwmon/hwmon2/power1_cap: Invalid argument
ghoti@fish:~$
```

Tools like `rocm-smi` use the same sysfs interface and fail in the same way.

How can I get more than 110W out of this card that is [supposed to be able to do 300W](https://www.amd.com/en/products/professional-graphics/instinct-mi25)?

Answer (score 0):

(I found my own solution, sorry if this is bad etiquette. I just don't want anyone else to suffer through this, and I hate the idea of people throwing away perfectly good silicon.)

### The problem

The VBIOS parameter "TDPODLimit" (Thermal Design Power OverDrive Limit) is set to 0% on this card for whatever reason. Maybe the original users of this card (which are mostly large cloud companies) got custom drivers from AMD that worked around the issue?

### The solution

THIS MAY BE DANGEROUS. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.

I patched the kernel driver to pretend that the TDPODLimit is 75% and ignore the maximum OverDrive parameter in the BIOS. This is similar to [what AMD's WattMan](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106374) apparently does on Windows. Note that **this policy applies to all AMD GPUs in your system**, not just the Radeon Instinct ones. Be careful not to burn out your card(s) by setting the power limit too high on them. Note that this patch only affects the maximum power limit that you can *optionally* set on the cards. At boot time, the cards will always start off with their predefined normal limit (in this case 110W).

Also note that "TDP" might not be the same thing as the OverDrive "power limit". It might be that the power limit is applied only to the chip power but the TDP also includes the voltage regulators and other components which also dissipiate power. To play it safe, if your card is rated for a TDP of 300W, set your power limit well below 300W. (Thanks
Tim Roberts for bringing this up!).

Also I think you might need to add `amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffffffff` to your [kernel commandline parameters](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/kernel_parameters) (like on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line in `/etc/default/grub`).

Here is the patch I applied:

```
--- drivers/gpu/drm/amd/pm/powerplay/amd_powerplay.c    2022-10-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0100
+++ drivers/gpu/drm/amd/pm/powerplay/amd_powerplay.c    2022-10-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0100
@@ -922,21 +922,22 @@
        if (hwmgr->hwmgr_func->set_power_limit == NULL) {
                pr_info_ratelimited("%s was not implemented.\n", __func__);
                return -EINVAL;
        }
 
        if (limit == 0)
                limit = hwmgr->default_power_limit;
 
        max_power_limit = hwmgr->default_power_limit;
        if (hwmgr->od_enabled) {
-               max_power_limit *= (100 + hwmgr->platform_descriptor.TDPODLimit);
+               /* max_power_limit *= (100 + hwmgr->platform_descriptor.TDPODLimit); */
+               max_power_limit *= (100 + 75);
                max_power_limit /= 100;
        }
 
        if (limit > max_power_limit)
                return -EINVAL;
 
        hwmgr->hwmgr_func->set_power_limit(hwmgr, limit);
        hwmgr->power_limit = limit;
        return 0;
 }
```

Result:

```shell
ghoti@fish:~$ echo 120000000 | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card1/device/hwmon/hwmon2/power1_cap
[sudo] password for ghoti: 
120000000
ghoti@fish:~$ cat /sys/class/drm/card1/device/hwmon/hwmon2/power1_cap
120000000
```

### Is it getting too hot?

**DO NOT REPLACE THERMAL PASTE BEFORE READING THE FOLLOWING WARNING** If the card is older than 2-3 years, you might want to replace the thermal paste using some nice **non-conductive** paste. Be extremely careful not to [touch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGgxShmACvw) the shiny [silicon interposer](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AMD@14nm@GCN_5th_gen@Vega10@Radeon_RX_Vega_64@ES-Sample@_Stack-DSC01160-DSC01176_-_ZS-retouched.jpg) that the visible chips seem to be resting on. You will **irreversibly damage** your [HBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Bandwidth_Memory)-based chip if you touch the interposer. Do not try to scrape off the dry thermal paste residue off the interposer as that could damage it. Basically do not do anything that could potentially scratch it.